# Python pytds - Getting output from Microsoft SQL server commands

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I'm attempting to write a quick Python program that executes the "sp_updatestats" command on a Microsoft SQL server. I think I have the actual command working, but I don't know for sure because I don't think I have the logging working properly. I want to get the messages returned from the server from running the command and write them to a log file, but I just can't suss it out.

If I use cur.fetchall(), I get: "Previous Statement didn't produce any results"

If I use cur.messages, I get: []

If I use cur.return_value, I get: 0

I'm expecting a return like I would get if I ran "sqlcmd" from a command prompt with a "-o c:\log.txt" switch.

I'm using python 3.9

Here's my (sanitized) code:

```
    import pytds

    import datetime

    from pytds.login import NtlmAuth

    import pytds.extensions

    import time



    current_date = datetime.date.today()

    date_string = str(current_date)

    extention = '.txt'

    logname = 'log' + date_string + extention




    with pytds.connect('server', 'database', 'username', 'password') as conn:

        with conn.cursor() as cur:

        cur.execute("sp_updatestats")

        #results = cur.fetchall()

        #results = cur.get_proc_return_status()

        #results = cur.messages

        #results = cur.return_value

        resultstr = str(results)



    with open(logname, 'w') as f:

        f.write(resultstr)



    cur.close()

    quit()
```

Comment: Microsoft recommends using pyodbc and the Microsoft ODBC driver to connect to SQL Server. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: [*"Return Code Values 0 (success) or 1 (failure)"*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-updatestats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-code-values) so a return value of 0 would make sense